# how to change fashion_mnist shape

Tags: keras

I loaded Fahion_Mnist dataset through "fashion_mnist.load_data()" and I tried to train a ResNet50 neural network. But I don't know how reshape dataset image from (28,28,1) to (224,224,3), as needed as input in ResNet.

I am using Python 3, Keras 2.2.4

This is my code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing import image
from PIL import Image

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat','Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

IMAGE_SIZE    = (224,224)
NUM_CLASSES   = 10
BATCH_SIZE    = 8  # try reducing batch size or freeze more layers if your GPU runs out of memory
FREEZE_LAYERS = 2  # freeze the first this many layers for training
NUM_EPOCHS    = 20
WEIGHTS_FINAL = 'model_fashion_resnet.h5'

train_images = preprocess_input(train_images)
train_images = np.expand_dims(train_images, axis=0)

train_labels = preprocess_input(train_labels)
train_labels = np.expand_dims(train_labels, axis=0)

test_images = preprocess_input(test_images)
test_images = np.expand_dims(test_images, axis=0)

net = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None,
           input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE[0],IMAGE_SIZE[1],3))
x = net.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
output_layer = Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax', name='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=net.input, outputs=output_layer)
for layer in model.layers[:FREEZE_LAYERS]:
    layer.trainable = False
for layer in model.layers[FREEZE_LAYERS:]:
    layer.trainable = True
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-5), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())


inizio=time.time()


datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)



model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE),
                steps_per_epoch=len(train_images) / BATCH_SIZE, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)
```

And this is what I receive after run:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (224, 224, 3) but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28)
```

How to change MNIST images so that they can input in the ResNet50 neural network?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what are you trying to achieve with the tile? I'd guess the original image format is a 28x28 array of greyscale pixel values - isn't that what Pillow wants already? And I'd guess you'd need to tell Image.fromarray that this is greyscale input (mode='L' ?) and that it should convert the resized image back into a bitmap in RGB mode.

Comment: But feeding a neural network x8^2 scaled up images feels wrong. I wouldn't be surprised if this didn't work very well.

Comment: I updated the post with the complete code and I removed the "tile", that is the error of different shape.

Comment: OK: this now sounds like it's expecting a single RGB image (224x224 image dimensions x3 colours per pixel) but you're giving it the array of 60,000 greyscale images at 28x28 (with one greyscale sample per pixel). Apologies I'm not sure what to suggest.